# Fix error "Cannot determine the packages folder to restore NuGet packages"

Tags: nuget, restore

I'm getting the following error during the Azure Cloud Build process. How can I fix the problem?

> "##[error]Cannot determine the packages folder to restore NuGet packages. Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory."

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error verbatim after running `nuget.exe restore` on a project that didn't actually reference any NuGet packages, however, within the project's directory sat a `packages.config` file containing an entry to a package. This config file was not included or referenced by the project, it was just sitting in the directory.

Deleting the stray `packages.config` file resolved the error.

Answer (score -2):

Just like the build log said, you should give a argument the `-PackagesDirectory` or `-SolutionDirectory` to specify a folder to store the packages.

Check the [restore options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-restore#options) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not really that cut and dry. The help for this field states: "Specifies the folder in which packages are installed. If no folder is specified, packages are restored into a packages/ folder alongside the selected solution, packages.config, or project.json."

So why isn't the default value used?

Comment: Nope, it does not help!